# div jumping horizontally

Tags: html, css

In the site i'm creating (http://ieangh.kroltan.eliti.com.br/ - all code here), my `#content_wrap` div jumps to the right when the first nav button is hovered, and its contents move down when any other navbuttons are hovered. It does'nt seem to find the problem in my CSS... I beleive that it's something with the structure of my site, but i've tried putting the navbar in the `#content_wrap`, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `min-height` of your navigation buttons changes on hover:

```
.navbtn:hover {
    min-height: 28px;
}
.navbtn {
    min-height: 25px;
}
```

One way to fix the jump would be to compensate for the different height with margins:

```
.navbtn:hover {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbtn {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, just found the same, you beat me to it! :D Another way to fix this is to put a clear:both div below the nav options, e.g. `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`

Comment: @Jeroen That makes the blue part of the header go all the way down in the header.
@thirtydot Unfortunately now the whole `#content_wrap` div moves, nt just what was inside of it.

Comment: @Kroltan: What browser are you testing in? I was using Chrome and I also tested in Firefox. It works in both when my changes are applied with Developer Tools/Firebug. You don't appear to have put the changes I suggested live.

Comment: Ah kk, best follow @thirtydot's suggestion then. By the way, if you worry about the structure of your site: have a look at [the W3 validator](validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fieangh.kroltan.eliti.com) service, which may (probably will) help you identify some problems.

Comment: @Jeroen I tested then removed. But i tried using Firebug and now it works! What a weird thing. And TY for the link.